# Why does my TimerTask.cancel() returns an NPE ? (JAVA)

Tags: java, timer, nullpointerexception, timertask

I'm coding an assignment and currently everything's working fine. I'm not going to post the whole thing but the essential classes being called and referenced.

Basically, my problem is that I have a GameTimer class to start a Timer in my Game:

```
public class GameTimer  {

    GameViewController gvc = GameFrame.gameViewController;
    public static boolean isRunning = false;

    public int seconds = 0;

    public Timer timer = null;
    public TimerTask task = null;

    public GameTimer () {
        timer = new Timer();
    }

    public void start() {
        task = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                gvc.updateTime(seconds);
                seconds++;
            }
        };
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 1000, 1000);
        System.out.println("Task was started");
        isRunning = true;
    }

    public void stop() {
        task.cancel();
        timer.cancel();
        timer.purge();
        isRunning = false;
    }

    public void restart() {
        stop();
        start();
    }
}
```

And basically I have different modes that extends a GameModel and references my GameTimer instance in my GameModel class :

```
public class GameModel {
    public GameTimer game_timer = new GameTimer();
    //... Rest of instances and classes
}

public class Mode1 extends GameModel {
    public Mode1() {
        if(!gamer_timer.isRunning)
            game_timer.start();
        else
            game_timer.restart();
    }
    //.....Rest of methods
}

public class Mode2 extends GameModel {
    public Mode2() {
        if(!gamer_timer.isRunning)
            game_timer.start();
        else
            game_timer.restart();
    }
    //.....Rest of methods
}
```

Basically, my game is a GUI and i have a drop-down box from which I select my modes. My game instantly loads Mode1 when it runs, but when I choose Mode2, it returns a NullPointerException on my

```
  task.cancel();
```

I've read on some other posts that you have to cancel the TimerTask before the Timer, but whether I put timer cancel before the task cancel
       task.cancel
       timer.cancel()
it still gives me the same NullPointerException

Here's the error:

```
  Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" Mode2
  java.lang.NullPointerException
       at GameTimer.stop(GameTimer.java:32) // task.cancel()
       at GameTimer.restart(GameTimer.java:39)
       at Mode2.<init>(Mode2.java:15)
```

Can you help me just figure out why is the task not cancelling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why is `isRunning` static?

Mode1 sets it to true. Mode2 is created and it *should* read false for *isRunning* but instead it reads true (class variable = only one used) so instead of calling *start( )* it calls *restart( )* and gets the NPE because it was never started and so can't be stopped.

Comment: You're right I'm sorry there's a line I forgot to add. I edited my code. In my stop() method is set isRunning to false;

Comment: Do you stop( ) Mode1 before you start( ) Mode2? If you don't the value of *isRunning* will be true when you expect it to be false

Comment: I'm sorry, I mean to say that in my stop() method, isRunning is being set to false. I'm going to make isRunning as a getter() for better coding but for now, I don't think making it static will affect my current Code.

Comment: No i dont stop mode1 before i start mode2. I start in mode1 before I stop in mode2

Comment: I still think your problem is you made this variable static when it should not be.

Comment: Ok, I tried your way. I created a getTimerState() that return a bool to get isRunning. Now it doesn't return a NullPointer, thank you, however when I switch mode, it seems like there are two imer tasks running at the same, overlapping together.

Comment: Update your question/code to show it's current state

Comment: I will, your idea actually helped figure out my probleme, thanks! But I'll post my complete solution when I figure out a way to do it by myself hahaha.

Comment: Great. Feel free to accept this answer if it worked for you

Answer (score 0):

I didn't clearly read your explanation line by line but what I can say by seeing your code is that,

Here inside `restart()` method you are calling `stop()` first and `start()` second

```
public void restart() {
        stop();
        start();
    }
```

Inside the start() method you are initializing your `task` object like here

```
 public void start() {
        task = new TimerTask()
```

But as per your code this seems second priority of your code, `stop()` is called at first, But at that time `task` was not initialized. I suggest you to rearrange this as per your needs and initialize `task` anywhere you feel comfortable but be sure you initialized before using.

Comment: Hi, I think I understand what you're saying and thanks for replying by the way. However, my `start()` is called before anything else, it's only when I change from `Mode1` to `Mode2` that my `restart()` calls because of the `isRunning`, it checks return `true` that the timer is running therefore it calls for `restart()`.

Comment: And what if you seperate TimerTask in separate class and use it like shown [here](http://www.iitk.ac.in/esc101/05Aug/tutorial/essential/threads/timer.html). What ever happened is just as I described in the answer. And the only solution you need to apply is to initialize this first. Either by changing the combinations of isRunning state apart from you currently doing now. Or anything else logic.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help. I found the solution. Mode1 is being initialized as I run the game

```
 new Mode1 ();
```

and the same Mode2. It would initilized when I choose Mode2 in my game. However, because I'm reinitializing the same gameModel over my program, the isRunning would always be false at first because in my GameModel, you see me create a new instance of my GameTimer everytime. So basically, the state of the timer would never be set to true.

I've found the problem to my code but I have figured a solution yet so I will post the solution as soon I am done with it. Thank you for helping